# Limit involving product of consecutive terms and factorials.

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

I want to show that 
$$\dfrac{\alpha^{N}N‎!}{\prod_{l=0}^{N-1}\left(\left(N+l\right)\alpha+1\right)}\rightarrow 0$$
when $N\rightarrow \infty$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

Thanks.

Comment: Look at the quotient of consecutive terms.

Answer (score 1):

For $α=0$ this is trivial. Else, denote the $N-$th term with $x_N$. Then you have that $$x_{N+1}=x_N\cdot\frac{αN+α}{2αN+1}=x_N\cdot\frac{N+1}{2N+\frac1α}<x_N$$ for sufficiently large $N$ and for any value of $a\neq 0$. So, (eventually) decreasing and bounded below by $0$, the sequence converges to $L$ with $$L=L\cdot\frac12\implies L=0$$

Comment: Much simpler and elegant that my junk !!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Hahaha, I just copy-righted the comment to compare consecutive terms, so I am not so proud of my (not so) original effort either...

Answer (score 1):

*This is more than likely a too complex answer.*

Using  Pochhammer notation $$\prod_{l=0}^{N-1}\Big((N+l)\alpha+1\Big)=\alpha ^{N-1} (\alpha  N+1) \left(N+\frac{1}{\alpha }+1\right)_{N-1}=\frac{\alpha ^N \,\Gamma \left(2 N+\frac{1}{\alpha }\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(N+\frac{1}{\alpha }\right)}$$ This makes $$P_n=\frac{\alpha^{N}N‎!}{\prod_{l=0}^{N-1}\Big((N+l)\alpha+1\Big)}=\frac{\Gamma (N+1)\, \Gamma \left(N+\frac{1}{\alpha }\right)}{\Gamma \left(2
   N+\frac{1}{\alpha }\right)}$$ Taking logarithms and using Stirling approximation, you should get $$\log(P_n)=-2 N \log (2)+\left(\log \left(\sqrt{\pi }\, 2^{1-\frac{1}{\alpha }}\right)+\frac{1}{2}
   \log \left(N\right)\right)+\frac{\alpha ^2-2 \alpha +2}{8 \alpha ^2
   N}+O\left(\frac{1}{N^2}\right)$$